# get file from server using file url

Tags: php

i try to store file on server "public/image" folder and it store the file. but when i try to read or check file is exist using  url:::"http://www.myapp.net/image/image_654391973.txt" it returns 
not exist. and all permission of image folder and file are set to read and write("0777").

here is my test code:

```
 <?php

    $FileName="/home/a/public_html/image/"."image_".rand().".txt";
    $binary="hello";
    $Event_file = fopen($FileName, "wb");
    fwrite($Event_file, $binary);
    fclose($Event_file);
    $Path=realpath($FileName);

 //get image file
    $get_path="http://www.myapp.net/image/image_654391973.txt";
echo $get_path ."<br>";
   if(is_file($get_path))
{
echo "file exists on server";
}
else
{
echo "file not exists on server ";
}
?>
```

file is store on folder but it return  "file not exists on server"

Comment: `is_file` doesn't work with `http:` URLs. It only works with URL schemes that support `stat`, see http://us1.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php

Answer (score 0):

If you will check [is_file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-file.php), you will see that it will get a path to a file, not a url to a file.

You will need to change your code accordingly :

```
 <?php

    $FileName="/home/a/public_html/image/"."image_".rand().".txt";
    $binary="hello";
    $Event_file = fopen($FileName, "wb");
    fwrite($Event_file, $binary);
    fclose($Event_file);
    $Path=realpath($FileName);

 //get image file
    $get_path="/home/a/public_html/image/image_654391973.txt";
echo $get_path ."<br>";
   if(is_file($get_path))
{
echo "file exists on server";
}
else
{
echo "file not exists on server ";
}
?>
```

Comment: This won't tell you if the file is visible through the webserver.

Answer (score 0):

The `http:` wrapper doesn't support `stat()`, so `is_file` can't tell whether the URL points to a real file. Try:

```
if ($temp = fopen($get_path, 'r')) {
    close($temp);
    echo "file exists on server";
} else {
    echo "file not exists on server";
}
```

Comment: Warning: fopen() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /public/app/test.php

Comment: I assume you figured out by now to add the missing `mode` argument. I've updated the answer.